# Can I change v8 version used by node.js?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

I am writing a node.js C++ addon and it behaves differently in two identical node.js versions but with different v8 versions. So I want to make the v8 versions identical as well to see if the different v8 versions causes the different behavior.

To reproduce this, you could open VSCode's "about" and see there node.js and V8 version. The v8 version of VSCode's V8 is different (and ends with `-electron`) from what is used in the regular node.js of the same version (`node -p process.versions.v8`, ends with `-node`).

In my case I have these versions:

- VSCode: Node.js 10.11.0, V8 6.9.427.31-electron.0
- Regular Node.js: 10.11.0, V8 6.8.275.32-node.28

Comment: `two identical node.js versions but with different v8 versions` can you produce a [mcve]? My understanding was that any given version of Node.js ships with a particular version of v8. If that's not the case, this is news to me.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I am sorry, I've added the reproduction instructions.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what you meant, I've been able to reproduce what you're seeing now. Are you attempting to run the C++ addon within a VSCode extension? That's the only reason that the v8 version of your VSCode editor would matter.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Great! Basically yes, the addon is used by the TypeScript extension ([this](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/master/extensions/typescript-language-features) I guess), via a TypeScript's language [plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin).

Comment: I don't know if it's possible to change the version of v8 used by a particular Node.js runtime, but I don't think verifying v8 version as the "cause" of the problem will solve anything. Your time would probably be better spent attempting to debug the issue on the VSCode Node.js runtime and stepping through the problematic code line-by-line using LLDB. [Here's an article that provides instructions for debugging right in VSCode](https://medium.com/@atulanand94/debugging-nodejs-c-addons-using-vs-code-27e9940fc3ad) (which may or may not require multiple instances running in your case, not sure).

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Wow, that's some valuable insights! Didn't know there's an easy (seems so) way to debug node addons right in VSCode, thanks! Regarding the first part, yep, I thought the same way, you just confirmed my thougths. Asked just in case anyone knows and for the future searchers :-) Thanks again, I'll try that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

V8 developer here. For the record and future searchers: V8, *in general*, does not promise API or ABI stability between versions, so by default, a given Node.js version (just like any other V8 embedder, e.g. Chromium-based browsers) is compatible with exactly one V8 version.

That said:

- the required changes to adapt to a new API version are usually fairly small and straightforward; but they do require you to change some C++ code and recompile Node. (There have been a few exceptions over the past decade, where significant work was required.)
- sometimes we (V8 team) have a reason to make an exception and actually guarantee ABI stability over a small range of versions. IIRC around the release of Node 10 was such a time; 6.8 and/or 6.9 may well have been in that range, I'm not sure.
- sometimes you might get lucky: nothing significant has changed, and an earlier or later version just works :-)

In the case at hand, I agree with @PatrickRoberts' suggestion that debugging is probably more useful than bisecting.

Comment: Thank you, interesting insight! I must say that I have debugged an app, and found that Patrick and you are right. There was a small undefined behavior bug, that behaved differently. Removing the UB fixed the issue :-)